# How to append all the same class jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

in my website, I want to append a div below to a class, I have a lot of same class. The website is selling T-shirt, each item has the .color class. Each time, when I refresh the page, it only append to one item, when I go to the second item, the div won't append. #myshop is loading from other site, so that's why I need to use append to add the message. The reason I use setTimeout because #myshop is be load after the page load, so I have to delay it. You can check it out on my url, www.sayhitoworld.com,  click any item, you will see the message below the color, go back, and click another item, the message won't append any more. Appreciate your time.

```js
jQuery('#myshop').one('click', function(){
 setTimeout(append_color, 1000);
});

function append_color(){
 jQuery('.color').append("<div id='append_color' >Note: If the T-shirt had the same color as the character's hair or body, you won't see the shape, still cool though.</div>");
 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are the items on the same page?  If so this div will only append to the first item because of the div has an ID.  ID's need to be unique so only one div called append_color can exist per page.  Why not append a class called append_color and see if that works for you.

```
function append_color(){
    $('.color').each(function(){
        $(this).append("<div class='append_color' >Note: If the T-shirt had the same color as the character's hair or body, you won't see the shape, still cool though.</div>");
    });
}
```

Comment: yes, they are in the same page, I try class, still won't work.

Comment: @conan I made an edit which incorporates using .each and using a class instead of an ID.  Note that if you use the class you must change your #append_color to .append_color in your css.  You will not be able to use more than one ID on any given page so whatever method you end up using it will need to incorporate a class.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I figure it out myself. Actually, everybody's way is right, the only thing I have to do is need to delay the whole script to load. I don't really understand that. But #myshop is a link from other website, so every script I write, I need to delay them. Thanks

Comment: Glad you figured it out! @conan

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('.color').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(obj).append(<your_template>);
});
```

Comment: There's no reason to wrap `append` with `each`, as it already does that internally.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, instead of [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) (if possible), that is why the function only fires once. From the docs:

> **.one( events [, data ], handler ):**
>   Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   at most **once** per element per event type.

Try something like this instead:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#myshop', function(){
    setTimeout(append_color, 1000);
});

function append_color(){
    jQuery('.color').append("<div id='append_color' >Note: If the T-shirt had the same color as the character's hair or body, you won't see the shape, still cool though.</div>");  
}
```